# error TS1005: ';' expected after install angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

I have this problem after install angular material. I already updated typescript global version to latest version.

tsc -v = Version 4.5.2

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:64 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                  ~~~
node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:69 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                       ~~~
node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:82 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;

node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:83 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
                                                                                     ~
node_modules/@angular/material/core/common-behaviors/constructor.d.ts:14:85 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

14 export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: what is the version of local project typescript installation? it can be found in the project folder in the file `package.json`

Comment: I changed my package.json to 4.5.2. I don't know if I did it correctly. Before it was 3.6.4.

Comment: Can  you reinstall NPM and check once.

Comment: after changing the package.json call `npm install` in the directory